# Slide on gallery app

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently working on a app that is a like a gallery app. The app need to load some images from the resources folder and when the user selects one, the app should load the selected image, and if the user slides the screen, the app should load the next image or the previous image.

The problem I have is that when I click the image the app always loads the first image. I try to use a intet with a int to solve it, but the program gives me an error.

I'm quite new in android programing, sorry if it is a simple question.

Here is the code of the app:

**Main activity:**

```
package com.example.erasor.pruebaslide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void Image1 (View view) {
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, Slide.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void Image2 (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Slide.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", 2);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**Slide activity:**

```
package com.example.erasor.pruebaslide;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class Slide extends AppCompatActivity {



private CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;


private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

int[] mResources = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
};

class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slide, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object    object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the part where you tell the mViewPager which position to display, try this:

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```